# When using subprocess.run python script failes to find module

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a python script that launches several other script inside powershell
Every script works fine when I run python  in powershell.
when I use subprocess.run inside the master script it does not work.

This is how I invoke the scripts:

```
subprocess.run(["powershell", "-Command", self.ScriptPath], capture_output=False)
```

The specific script has the following imports at the top

```
import os
import sys
from datetime import datetime
import time
import pandas as pd
import pandas_ta
import requests
```

the one that failes is the pandas_ta import with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "XXX", line 7, in <module>
    import pandas_ta as pandasTA
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_ta'
```

the pandas import works which is very strange.
Any thoughts?

Comment: do you use virtual environments?

Comment: @MarcoF. no. just python 3.8  interpreter

Comment: Do you have any old python installations that might be interfering? What do the ScriptPath scripts look like? Can you run simple python scripts? Start a script with: `import sys \n print(sys.path)` to check the python path. What comes out when you run `powershell -Command python -m pip list`?

Comment: @MarcoF. when I run : powershell -Command python -m pip list I can see the pandas_ta module. if I just open a powershell window and run python <script_that_fails> it runs perfectly. it only fails when I use subprocess.run

Comment: you run `powershell -Command python -m pip list` with `subprocess.run`?